# how to disable alphabetic key so that it cant be typed

Tags: asp.net

I have a text-box i want to disable alphabetic key and special keys......
just want to enter numeric keys(0-9).
If i press any alphabetic key,text-box remain empty,don't event type any character except 0-9.
tell me what should i use..

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="!" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" ControlToValidate="txtboxGAmountC"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

allow to enter all character after that it give error message...
i Don't even want to enter any character except 0-9...
suggest me......

Comment: use html input tag and use type="number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can do with using javascript function
function validateNumber(key)
{
//getting key code of pressed key
var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
var phn = document.getElementById('Idof text box');
//comparing pressed keycodes
if (!(keycode==8 || keycode==46)&&(keycode < 48 || keycode > 57))
{
return false;
}
else
{
//Condition to check textbox contains ten numbers or not
if (phn.value.length <10)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ASP well, but wouldn't it work to capture the key press event and cancel it, if the typed character is not a digit?

Comment: In visual basic there is a built-in function that disable keys.
i think there must be in asp.net